# How does direct memory access improve performance

Tags: memory, cpu, dma

A wikipedia article about DMA says that the cpu has to be put in a hold state to prevent bus contention since peripherals and cpu share the memory bus, but if the main way dma mechanism improves performance is by allowing cpu to be free for other tasks how can it perform other tasks if it can't access ram also
this Wikipedia article [bus mastering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_mastering) says there has to be bus arbitration ,other devices too can't access memory at same time another device is accessing it.

So how does DMA improve performance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

*An attempt to an answer:*
*Based on very old information, remembrance and TLDR on the ref article, so bear with me*

The main idea with DMA is that data transfer using...

> IO-circuitry -> CPU/Software -> Destination

is replaced by

> IO-circuitry -> Destination

... here shown as "input", but most often also possible as "output".

Software running on the CPU is quite a bit slower than "Direct Memory Access" - This due to the fact that the CPU has to do two things; Fetch and Store often for each byte/word/long - so is required to access the databus at least twice.
This compared to DMA which often involves modes where the transfer is set up once to allow a larger amount of data to be transferred in one go, "without intervention".
The CPU might have to wait, so a slight delay; depending on the "mode" (see ref article below).

Arbitration comes in as a necessity when there are several devices capable of using DMA.

ref:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access